# How to write a file while it's opened or used by other application?

Tags: java, file, io

How to write a file while it's opened or used by other application?

If it is possible, how can this be done? If it's not possible, why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the hosting platform. But consider that altering the data someone else is using without it has been designed to expect it, will induce unpredictable result.

Think yourself as the "application" solving a problem whose data are given to you on a piece of paper.

Which solution you will ever come to, if someone continuously change that piece of paper data during your calculation? How can you prove it can  even be correct?